# Pgadmin trying to connect to wrong user on MacOS

Tags: postgresql, macos, pgadmin, macos-big-sur

I'm using Mac OS Big Sur. I changed my user folder and then the issue happened when I tried to start pgadmin server. Pgadmin on web trying to connect to old macos user.

Let's say, I changed my user name from A to B, but pgadmin trying to connect to user A.

How to fix this?

[image]

Comment: Well the user would be the database user not the OS user. What the error message is showing is that either the Postgres server is not running  or it is up and not listening on the host and port indicated in the message. You need to verify the status of the server before you do anything else.

Comment: hi @AdrianKlaver , I can't connect to the server because I always getting a wrong password.

Answer (score 0):

already fixed the issue only with this command

```
pg_ctl -D /usr/local/var/postgres start
```